# Add Column % Frequencies to Stacked Bar Chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart

I am wondering if there is a simple solution to this - I am a SAS user and having a lot of difficulty figuring this out in R, but I am required to use R for an assignment I'm doing.

So, I have created a bar chart of PCR test results (positive or negative) by race. Basically, I want to add the % frequencies to each column to show that the distribution of positive vs. negative covid cases are pretty similar by race (less clear with counts). Here is my code:

```
 p<-ggplot(data=Data, mapping=aes(x=race, fill=pcr))
    p+geom_bar()
```

And here is an image of my graph.
[image: here]

I just want the % frequencies somewhere on there. Or, ideally, I'd like the y axis to be % instead of count? I feel like this should be a pretty simple request but I haven't been able to find a simple explanation anywhere. Thank you all!

Data Summary:
record_id              site          age
Length:1000        Tucson :612   Min.   :21.0
Class1:labelled    Phoenix:388   1st Qu.:29.0
Class2:character                 Median :37.0
Mode  :character                 Mean   :38.4
3rd Qu.:45.0
Max.   :90.0

```
                                    race
```

American Indian or Alaska Native         :190
Asian                                    :207
Black or African American                :403
Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander:  0
White                                    :200

```
                                ethnicity       sex      occupation
```

Hispanic or Latino or Spanish Origin    :477   Female:476   FR-C :175
Not Hispanic or Latino or Spanish Origin:523   Male  :499   FR-F :132
Other : 25   FR-L :130
HCP-A:154
HCP-I:148
HCP-N:129
Other:132
pcr        form_1_complete
Negative:792   Incomplete:   0
Positive:208   Unverified:1000
Complete  :   0

Comment: If your data `Data` is not too big, it would be much easier to help if you provide your data. Try using `dput(Data)` and paste result to your question.

Comment: There are 1,000 observations so it is too much but here is the summary:

Comment: Oh...Then does your data focus on `race` and `pcr`, having amount of those?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! Just need to add (position="fill") to geom_bar() Thanks anyways!

Comment: If you want `%` format, add `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))` line.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to do it without data, but try this:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=race, fill = pcr, group =pcr)) + geom_bar(aes(y=freq), stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```